# In factory_girl, how can I specify an attribute with the same name as another factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have two tables as follows:

```
POSITION TABLE:
POSITION_ID |SPORT_ID |PARENT_POSITION |SOURCE_ID |SOURCE_POSITION_NAME |
------------|---------|----------------|----------|---------------------|
1           |1        |1               |1         |Goalkeeper           |

LOCALIZED_POSITION TABLE:
LOCALIZED_POSITION_ID |POSITION_ID |LOCALE_ID |POSITION         |
----------------------|------------|----------|-----------------|
1                     |1           |1         |Goalkeeper       |
```

When I define this factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :localized_position do
    position_id { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    locale_id { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    position 'Goalkeeper'
  end
end
```

and call `FactoryGirl.create(:localized_position)` I get this error:

```
Position(#70280313353320) expected, got String(#70280311914580)
```

Seems it is expecting the object **position** because of the factory with the same name.

I already tried some changes without success, like:

```
self.position 'Goalkeeper'
```

and

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :localized_position do |f|
    f.position_id { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    f.locale_id { Faker::Number.number(2) }
    f.position { 'Goalkeeper' + Random.rand(1..100).to_s }
  end
end
```

but nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your doing an association and that's not how you do associations in FactoryGirl. The error is telling you it's expecting a Position model and you've assigned it a string.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :localized_position do
    position { create(:position) }
  end
end
```

Or possibly the other way around as I'm not sure if your doing STI or polymorphic association there. You have `position_id` in both tables which seems suspect.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :position do
    localized_position { create(:localized_position) }
  end
end
```